# Mixing Create and Update in on CRM save batch/transaction

Tags: transactions, dynamics-crm

I'm saving entities to CRM from a console app using the entities collections and relationships to build an entity structure and save in one batch using  OrgService.Create/OrgService.Update.

My issue now is I need to mix create and update in one transaction. I think the answer is "no you can't" but I could be wrong. Can this be done?

Thanks for any advice :-)

Answer (score 0):

There is [ExecuteTransactionRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.messages.executetransactionrequest.aspx) which was introduced at some point in CRM2015. I haven't personally used this one, but it may do what you need. The only thing I'd worry about is batching up too many operations in a single transaction.

There are also [Plug-ins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327941.aspx) which allow you to perform extra operations in the core transaction.

> Stages 20 and 40 are guaranteed to be part of the database transaction while stage 10 may be part of the transaction.

So if your console application created a record of entity type A, you could then have a plugin registered either pre-operation (Stage 20) and/or post-operation (Stage 40) which will run as a part of the core CRM transaction.

Comment: Is ExecuteTransactionRequest only available in 2015 _Online_ Update 1? Or should it work in in On-prem version too?

Comment: Works in 2016 on-prem, but not 2015. Sadly :-(